Converting draw calls to Texture2D in raylib
I want to apply some shader effects to a couple of draw calls using raylib, but I haven't found ways of implementing shaders without a texture.
I was wondering if I could refactor the function below to work as a Texture2D, and if so, how could I go about doing that?
void drawBoard(Color lineColor, Color boardColor){
  ClearBackground(Color(boardColor));

  DrawRectangleV( (Vector2){294, 100}, (Vector2){7, 600}, Color(lineColor));
  DrawRectangleV( (Vector2){494, 100}, (Vector2){7, 600}, Color(lineColor));

  DrawRectangle(100, 294, 600, 7, Color(lineColor));
  DrawRectangle(100, 494, 600, 7, Color(lineColor));
}


Solution:
To make shaders work with draw calls I just used BeginShaderMode(); before the calls

There is literally an example that does that on the raylib website...

The method in the example works great! But it hasn't yielded good results for the blur shader I'm trying to use, which is the blur shader, I'm going to ask about the shader in a separate post
